# Output All Edges of iGraph in R to XML

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph

I'm wanting to output all edges in a iGraph g to an XML file, which looks something like this:

```
<edges>
    <edge from="1" to "2" />
    <edge from="1" to "4" />
    ...
</edges>
```

I know I can get the list of edges using E(g), but I don't know how to grab each individual to and from for each edge to output to XML.

Also, I have set the name attribute for all vertices, and need to output their name---not their id.

Could someone give my some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: I can use get.edgelist(g), to convert the edge data to an array, and grab the edge data from it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `?write.graph` within R. The `igraph` package can export graph objects to a variety of formats.

Comment: While the types of built-in exporting capabilities are nice, I need to export in the format mentioned above.

Comment: Isn't that just graphml?  I believe that type is supported.